# How can one combine fill-paragraph with supercite?

Tags: emacs

I am using Emacs 23 and VM 8.1 to write and read email. I am using Supercite 3.1 to get fancy citations in my replies such as

```
Foo> bla bla bla ... When are you
Foo> resuming the work on our paper?
```

I would like to get the same features as fill-paragraph but on the citation. 
I see it working on commented parts in LaTeX-mode (with the same function fill-paragraph)q, so I assume that I just have to set-up the correct regular expression for fill-paragraph to do the job, but which one and through which hook?

---

### EXAMPLE

I would like that, after editing out "bla bla bla ..." to get the following

```
Foo> When are you
Foo> resuming the work on our paper?
```

and pressing M-q, to get a correctly filled citation such as

```
Foo> When are you resuming the work on 
Foo> our paper?
```

In LaTeX-mode, the equivalent would be to go from

```
% When are you
% resuming the work on our paper?
```

to

```
% When are you resuming the work on our paper?
```

### Later Addition

Supercite documentation suggests the use of  filladapt or gin-mode.
(http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/emacs/sc_4.html)

It is mentioned that "filladapt.el needs a bit rewriting to fit into Emacs today." on http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FillAdapt 
I tried it anyway without success.

Its alternative, gin-mode.el (http://www.gaertner.de/~neitzel/sw.html) is not available on the cvs server of its author.

Answer (score 1):

See [set-fill-prefix](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Fill-Prefix.html) (bound to <kbd>C-x .</kbd> by default).  In brief, move the point to the end of the `fill-prefix` ("Foo> " in your case) and press <kbd>C-x .</kbd>; subsequent `fill-paragraph` (<kbd>M-q</kbd>) will have the desired effect.

#### Edit(2011-02-27):

It works for me in text-mode, without any customization (i.e., I started emacs with "emacs -Q").  After <kbd>C-x .</kbd>, can you check if the `fill-prefix` is set correctly?  Pressing <kbd>C-h v fill-prefix</kbd> should show its value as the string "Foo> ".

Comment: I like the idea (especially for when I have several parts tagged with different sources), but M-q just does not do anything on a quoted paragraph (neither does M-x fill-paragraph). To which function is bound your M-q? (i.e. what is the result of C-h k M-q?)

Comment: OK, the combination fill-prefix and fill-paragraph does cut overlong lines into a nicer look, but it does not rearrange the lines (i.e. the equivalent of putting everything on a single line and then fill-paragraph), as fill-paragraph does on an unquoted text?

Answer (score 0):

You may have to use [FillAdapt](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FillAdapt) as suggested in the [docs](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/emacs/sc_4.html).

Comment: Thanks: I had overlooked this in the documentation.

It is mentioned that "filladapt.el needs a bit rewriting to fit into Emacs today." on http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FillAdapt but since its alternative, ginhttp://www.gaertner.de/~neitzel/sw.html)-mode.el, is not available on the cvs server of its author (

Comment: Doing a `(require 'filladapt)` and going to the buffer of choice and doing `M-x filladapt-mode` and highlighting a section of text with a prefix and doing `M-q` on it just worked for me.  I had 'Foo > ' for the prefix, but after the `M-q`, all lines except the first had 'Foo >' for the prefix.  How did it not work for you?